# How many n digit numbers can be formed using 1,2,3 which contain at least one 1 and one 3?

Tags: combinatorics

How many n digit numbers can be formed using $1,2,3$ which contain at least one $1$ AND one $3 $?

For $n= 5$,

$11133$ is valid.
$12312$ is valid.
$11122$ is not valid.
$33333$ is not valid

Please suggest a formula which works for all $n$,  $3\leq n\leq100$.

Comment: @ian for n=5 , i calculated (5C2)*2*3*3*3 ,but it seems to have repititions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$3^n - (2^{n+1}-1)$

$3^n$ is the total possible numbers that can be formed. From this, we subtract the following cases:

1) **no 1 and no 3** : 1 way

2) **atleast one 1 and no 3** : $2^n-1$ ways

3) **atleast one 3 and no 1** : $2^n-1$ ways

Answer (score 1):

This is a relatively simple example of "inclusion exclusion."

How many ways without the conditions?

How many with the only condition that there is no $1$?

How many with the only condition that there is no $3$?

How many with the only condition that there is no $1$ and no $3$?

Figure out how to combine these numbers to get your result.

Comment: is it 3^n-2*2^n+1

Comment: I'd try it on small $n$ to check.

Comment: Inclusion-exclusion FTW! I think "there is no 3 and no 5" is supposed to be "no 1 and no 3", right?

Comment: @JiK yes it is supposed to be "no 1 and no 3"

Comment: Yeah, will fix that.